# How can I tell if badge is possible to gain more than once?

Tags: discussion, badges

I think it should be clearly stated in the Badges section.

For example, consider Vox Populi bronze badge:

> Used the maximum 40 votes in a day.

This says nothing about possibility to get awarded with this badge multiple times.
I think that even bronze badges are something of an achievement for new users, and this improvement could make things less confusing.

Am I missing something, or the best way to tell if badge can be gained multiple times is to check profiles of most dedicated users and see if any of them has that particular badge `x3` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to learn this information.

- Click through any badge. For example, [popular question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/48/popular-question) says: *"Asked a question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times."*
- Any badge with the word '**first**' can only be awarded once. For example, [investor](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/29/investor) says: *"First bounty you offered on another person's question."*
- Many badges are obviously only awardable once. Example: [scholar](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/10/scholar) (*"Asked a question and accepted an answer."*)
- If you're still not sure, the thoroughly exhaustive [meta badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) will tell you everything you ever wanted to know about every badge.

The suggestion to make this information more explicit [has been made before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125048/symbol-variation-to-mark-badges-which-can-be-earned-more-than-once), but wasn't particularly popular.

Comment: Thank you. I just think that displaying the sentence *This badge can be awarded multiple times* not only on specific-badge site, but also in the complete list of badges would be much more clear. Or even some symbolic indication like *(Multiple)*.

Comment: @beam022 - I happen to agree with you, and upvoted the feature request I linked to. In fact, this was first asked for [way back in 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time). I suggest you vote for these also. SE feature requests are prioritised based on popularity, among other things.